# How can I bind an Sub to an Event by Code?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a simple Form. The form contains an `OnClick`-Event. When I print its value, I get `[Event Procedure]` as result.

How can I set this `event procedure` by vba-code?

I mean not bind a expression that uses a function.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, I answer by myself. After finishing the question I saw my problem:

`[event procedure]` is just a String. Set it and the sub with the correct name is connected.

> ```
> MyForm.OnClick = "[event procedure]"
> ```

After that `Form_OnClick()` is used as Eventhandler.